# Error with: Property Access Must Assign To The Property Or Use Its Value

Tags: vb.net, properties

recently i have been assigned a homework task to create any program i like with the use of polymorphism, inheritance etc so ive gotten pretty far with my application but ive come across an error which says :

> Property Access Must Assign To The Property Or Use Its Value.

I personally have no idea what that means and ive attached some of my code where the error is constructing:

```
If rdbRed.Checked And rdbChequredBlack.Checked And rdbVision.Checked And rdbTinted.Checked Then
            MiniCooperS.GetTotalCarPrice(MiniColour, MiniInterior, MiniPackages, MiniWindows)
Elseif...
```

so the error is showing somewhere within this code and ive been at it for hours and cant seem to figure it out.. Help is appreciated!!

THANKS!

Comment: A better title will help you get answers.

Comment: what does MiniCooperS.GetTotalCarPrice actually do?

Answer (score 1):

If your `getTotalCarPrice()` function returns a value (I'm assuming it returns an int or a String), you must assign that value to a variable. ie.

```
dim carPrice As Integer
If rdbRed.Checked And rdbChequredBlack.Checked And rdbVision.Checked And rdbTinted.Checked Then
        carPrice = MiniCooperS.GetTotalCarPrice(MiniColour, MiniInterior, MiniPackages, MiniWindows)
Elseif...
Else carPrice = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, what it actually does is that the properties for the car which i have set ie. colour, interior, packages etc.. it gets the price for all of those. ill have a go at that Jpauley.. thanks

Comment: Then jpauley is correct, you need to assign the return value.

Comment: the problem isnt occurring within the function, it is that MiniCooperS was assigned to the wrong class and i dont know how to assign it to the right one :/

Comment: Its okay guys i figured out what the issue was, it was the equation that i had it just a little mixed up   MiniCooperS.GetTotalCarPrice = CSng(StandardCarColour + ChequeredBlack + SportsPack + TintedWindows + InitalCarPrice) is what the right thing was and its working too.. i just had to declare and assign those as variables accordingly as to how i wanted the price to work :)

Comment: @Shah_Clique Just an FYI, normally the word 'get' prefixed implies that the code is a function that returns a value ie. a 'getter'. Other standard prefixes are 'set' for a setter and 'is' for functions that return a boolean.